# Getting "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" error in Easyocr

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

When  I run this code

```
import easyocr
import cv2

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(r"C:\Users\sephi\Downloads\ocr.jpg")
```

I got this error.How to solve this issue?

```
[ERROR]  raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: What are the permission on the file you are trying to access?

Comment: alwys put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). Ther are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be resolved but its a long process

first uninstall easyocr, torch and torchvision using terminal

```
pip uninstall easyocr
pip uninstall torch`
pip uninstall torchvision
```

after above step run

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

now if Git is install in your system simply install easyocr directly by original link
by command:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/jaidedai/easyocr.git
```

if git is not installed then install it from here : install git for windows : https://git-scm.com/download/win

after installation follow these steps :

1. Search for Advanced system settings
2. click on "Environment Variables"
3. Now under System Variables find "PATH" And click on it
4. minimize above screen and go to c drive and search and copy path of git.exe and cmd from git folder
   in my case it was :-
   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
5. Paste both address in "PATH" and click ok

You can also refer to :-
How to change environment variables : [Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/git-installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Finally when torchvision, torch, easyocr are latest in your system and git is installed
it should resolve your error