# I've modified Related Path, why does my flutter still say I don't have git in the path?

Tags: git, flutter, path

I've added the required path to the Path. I also reinstalled git and even Flutter. Rebooting the system is no use either. I hope you can help me solve this problem.
[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNt0t.png)

[Path of My system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYcs.png)

[Path of My User variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghMVo.png)

Comment: Have a look at link: [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15047](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15047)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem the same as this one:

[Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26620312/18386517)

Try add this to your path `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.