# git Error although my frontend is already initialized by git and now I want to save my backend by initialized it with git

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github

git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2

- git init
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I want to Push the whole project as one repository in which their are two folder one of frontend and one for backend.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have Git installed. Or you don't have Git in your PATH.

Some solutions for adding git to path can be found at [Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/git-installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows) (Do this if you already installed Git).

If you don't have Git, please download and install it. Windows does not come preinstalled with it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the git is either not installed properly and/or its path is not added to your system variables.

Now coming up to your question, if you want to push both frontend and backend under the same repository you need to make sure they have some folder in common.

A simpler way would be to create a folder with your project name and initialize git there. Now move both the folders containing the front end and the back end inside this parent folder.