# git Permission denied (publickey), on every connect

Tags: git, ssh

I try to simplify my work with git, then i try to pull my repository with

```
git pull
```

i get "Permission denied (publickey), i solve this by two commands:

```
1. ssh-agent /bin/bash 

2. ssh-add /root/.ssh/mykey
```

Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/mukey *** - now i cat use "git pull"

but then i connect next time via ssh i must reenter this two commands again and again

how to make it auto init to skip this steps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have:

- an ssh config file specifying all the details of your ssh connection.

  ```
  cat ~/.ssh/config

  Host yourserver
  Hostname upstream.server.com
  User git                          # or the right user account to use on your server
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/mykey
  ```
- change the remote url

  ```
  git remote set-url origin ssh://yourserver:yourRepo.git
  ```
- add the agent and `ssh-add` command in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

  - One approach is described, for instance, in "[Configuring Git over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595863/6309)".
  - Another approach in "[How to run (git/ssh) authentication agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077302/6309)"

    1. Add a file called .bashrc to your home folder
    2. Open the file and paste in:

       ```
       #! /bin/bash 
       eval `ssh-agent -s` 
       ssh-add /root/.ssh/mykey
       ```