# GIT permission denied (public key)

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key, git-bash

Until yesterday, I was working on a project and every 20 minutes I was making pushes to my remote Git repository. Every time I made a push, I was asked for username and password, and that started to make me annoyed. I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh) and tried the answer from Muein Muzamil, so in my git bash I typed:

`git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:my_username/my_project.git`

Then my problems start. Now I can't make pushes it's giving me:
[this message](http://imageshack.com/a/img593/1599/aery.png). I haven't set up keys or did something similar, I just typed command that I mentioned above. I then tried to unset the remote.origin.url property but it's not pushing again, it says [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img811/6661/k00a.png). Now I just want to undo my changes, I will type my username and password every time if necessary but I need to make pushes to my repo.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Read the link posted by @NevikRehnel above about how to create and upload your public key to github. Then to revert your configuration just open the `.git/config` file and set the correct origin again. If you're unsure how that should look just clone the github repository to another location and compare the config files.

Comment: thanks for such quick response :) It solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't set up keys or did something similar, I just typed command that I mentioned above.

And that’s the problem with blindly following suggestions in answers to completely different questions :)

You basically told Git now to connect and authenticate via SSH but didn’t give it a single information on how that actually works. SSH uses a a private/public key combination which requires you to generate those first on your machine and upload the *public* one to GitHub then.

Please see [this help document](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) by GitHub on how to set up your SSH keys correctly and how to add the public key to your account.