# The git ssh agent is running but is not saving my username or password

Tags: windows, git, powershell, ssh-agent, posh-git

### Initial Setup

I am using Posh-Git and have followed [Phil Haack's advice](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/) for using SSH. That is, I have done the following:

1. Install msysgit.
2. Update Posh-Git
3. Add the ssh-agent to PATH.

### Initial Test

Now, when I start Powershell, the ssh-agent does start. This is good. If I run `Get-Proces` I can see it:

```
 91       8     1728       4208   286     0.23   2520 ssh-agent
```

When it starts, though, it does not ask me for my username and password. This is not good.

Further, during a single PowerShell session, git repeatedly asks me for my username and password, and never remembers it.

### Finding my SSH Keys

My SSH keys are located in `C:\Users\<my-user>\.ssh`, in which I can see two files:

```
github_rsa
github_rsa.pub
```

I have gone ahead and run `ssh-add "C:\Users\<my-user>\.ssh\github_rsa"`.

Still the agent doesn't remember my credentials.

### Testing with Git Shell

msysgit comes with the Git Shell, and when I run it, the authentication just goes right through perfectly. I am never asked for a username and password, at all.

I have looked at the answer here [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh), which recommends checking whether we're using https or the ssh protocol.

```
git config -l
```

In both my Git Shell and my normal Windows PowerShell prompt, the repositories are all using HTTPS.