# How to tell git to always use SSH?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, clone

I search many questions, like this [Configuring Git over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh) but the answers just configure the remote URI for a particular project. I want a global effect.

What I want is when I clone over HTTPs

```
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```

and git will transform the call into SSH

```
git clone git@github.com:octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```

How to do this ?

Comment: I doubt that there is a good way to do what you are asking. HTTPS and SSH are different protocols. There is nothing guaranteeing that a Git server will provide both, and there is no general way to translate between equivalent URLs. Why can't you just use the SSH URL when you initially clone a repository?

Comment: @Chris I use Cocoapods, they use clone over HTTPs