# Git for windows 7 failing to clone the repo from github

Tags: git, github, windows-7, git-bash

I have git repo https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal I'm working with it using linux box (Xubuntu) it work fine but when I've try to clone it using Windows 7 git bash I got this error:

```
jankiewj@RWAMW35281 MINGW64 /c/docs $ git clone
https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal.git Cloning into
'jquery.terminal'... fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https'

jankiewj@RWAMW35281 MINGW64 /c/docs $ git clone
git@github.com:jcubic/jquery.terminal.git Cloning into
'jquery.terminal'... The authenticity of host 'github.com
(192.30.252.130)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8. Are you sure you
want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
exists.

jankiewj@RWAMW35281 MINGW64 /c/docs
```

Is there a way to clone using https I don't want to add ssh key from windows box to GitHub.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the last version of git for Windows could handle that. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Philippe 2.6.3.windows.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding https, check if there is no strange characters, [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30474447/6309).

I just typed:

```
git clone https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal
```

It worked just fine.

For ssh, you would indeed need to add your public key to your GitHub account, and check the value of `echo $HOME`.