# How to solve git clone error in gitbash

Tags: git-bash, git-clone

I installed gitbash and generated ssh keys and copied it to my bitbucket account.

I tried clone a repository.

I'm getting an error as:

`Git clone “fatal: I don't handle protocol 'ssh'”`

Please help me how to fix this and clone to my repo

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the commands you used?  It is possible that you have inadvertently copied unicode characters into the command.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474447/git-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must copy pasted the clone url, there will be white space in the clone URL.

Just make sure there is no whitespace in the clone url, if you are not sure just type the  clone URL followed by 'git clone'

```
git clone https://github.com/your-repository-clone-no-white-space
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
git init
git clone https://github.com/your-clone-Url
```