# How to capture the output of git clone command running from python subprocess

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to run `git clone` command using `subprocess.check_output()` so that I can verify if it clones successfully or not, but its throwing error.

```
Command 'git clone <url>' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

I am doing:

```
resp = subprocess.check_output('git clone <url>', shell=True)
```

How can I get the output of git clone so that I can verify it worked fine or not and can catch any errors if any.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the git clone command? Like `proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`? Then you can use `proc.stdout.read()`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I am using subprocess.check_output not with Popen, but I'll try it and will update.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Can you answer the question by giving an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the best method to read a subprocess' output is to use `subprocess.PIPE`. For example

```
import subprocess
from collections import namedtuple

def git_clone(url):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return namedtuple('Std', 'out, err')(process.stdout.read(), process.stderr.read())

# test on fake url
out, err = git_clone('http://fake.url')
print('out = {}\nerr = {}'.format(out, err)
```

outputs:

```
out = b''
err = b"Cloning into 'fake.url'...\nfatal: unable to access 'http://fake.url/': Couldn't resolve host 'fake.url'\n"
```

Hence you can test success by changing the function to be

```
from warnings import warn

def git_clone(url):

    process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    if not process.stdout.read():
        warn(process.stderr.read())
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got output `b"Cloning into 'Project'...\nfatal: I don't handle protocol 'git clone https'\n"`

Comment: That's a git problem, not a python problem. What url did you pass?

Comment: But that same url is working fine on terminal without python :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474447/git-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-http sounds like you have a non-ascii character in there

Comment: Hi, it is so strange that when the clone succeed, it only prints the first line but in err:
```out = b'' err = b"Cloning into 'sshuttle'...\n"```, any suggestions?

Comment: Same, i only get the first line, anyone know why? @K.Symbol