# Azure CLI: I dont handle protocol

Tags: git, azure-cli

I am trying to install a file from a private repo. I am using azure cli run commands to invoke these actions.

Here is what the run command looks like:

```
az vm run-command invoke --name ${MONITOR_VM_NAME} \
            --command-id RunShellScript \
            --resource-group ${RSC_GRP_NAME} \
            --scripts "
                        curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash 
                        sudo yum -y install nodejs
                        cd /etc/
                        sudo git clone \${REPO_USER_NAME}:\${REPO_PASSWORD}@https://bar.visualstudio.com/Foo/_git/Eth-Netstats

           "
```

Unfortunately , I am receving this in the output:

> fatal: I don't handle protocol
>   ':@https'

I have looked here:

https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-git/issues/965

and

[git: fatal: I don't handle protocol '​​http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474447/git-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-http)

but it doesnt seem to help. I would appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: The syntax for coding a literal user name and password into an `http` or `https` URL is: `https://user:password@host.example.com/text?passed&to=host`. That is, the `user:password` part goes *after* the `https://` part, before the host name.

Comment: Thanks so silly of me. Please add as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for coding a literal user name and password into an `http` or `https` URL is: `https://user:password@host.example.com/text?passed&to=host`. That is, the `user:password` part goes after the `https://` part, before the host name.

(The above is moved from a comment, and formatted a bit.)

Note that ssh URLs can use a similar form: `ssh://user:password@host.example.com/...`, though it's even worse to include a plaintext password in an ssh URL given that ssh works so hard to prevent plaintext passwords.  (Plaintext passwords are a bad idea everywhere, but at least with https, one has the excuse that there's less standardization in this area.)  But Git has a special form, recognizing `user@host:...` as shorthand for `ssh://user@host/...`.

Aside: The security concerns I express above are totally blown out of the water with:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash
```

I realize this is a standard way people use to install nodejs (visit https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x to see).  I just wish it weren't.