# Using git with SSH remote repo on Windows

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I used `git bash` to clone an SSH repo (e.g. `ssh://user@host:/var/www/git/www.git`). When doing the clone it asked me for the password, which I entered on the command line. It managed to clone the repo.

Now every time I want to pull / push it asks me for the password. How can I automate this step?

Comment: You should take a look into adding an SSH key to your github account - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/#platform-windows

Comment: The repo isn't on Github though.

Comment: Then you can configure a ssh key for your user on the host machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure you've used SSH (and not HTTPS), then you should have set a key to identify yourself, and the password you mention must be the passphrase of your key.

Then you should use a ssh-agent (or KeyChain in MacOS) to remember your password during the whole session.

Another (unsecure) way is to remove teh passphrase form your SSH key.