# git require password for ssh server each time

Tags: git, ssh

I have limited access to server. What I did:

**Server:**

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
```

**My local pc (windows):**

```
git clone myusername@myserver.com:project.git
// make some files
git commit -m 'init'
git push
```

I can work with no problem using my server (push, pull, branch, whatever). Problem is that each operation require password and it is annoying (I have long passwords).

I was trying this: `git config credential.helper store`

---

**Edit after @VonC answer**

**This is about SSH config, not GIT.** The solution IS available in topic [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595858/1587715) but is on the bottom with only 17 votes.

1. I've already had configured GIT ssh key.
2. Only thing I had to do was `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub userlogin@sshserver.com`*. Done! No more password need.

Full process, including generating ssh key can be found here: [SSH with authentication key instead of password](https://debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password)*

*ssh commands are available from git-bash on Windows

Comment: You need an ssh connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the result of

```
ssh -Tv myusername@myserver.com
```

That will show you which ssh key it is trying: you need your public ssh key to be on the server side, at `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys` in order for your ssh connection to *not* default to the username/password authentication scheme.

Comment: Thank you my friend! I will describe whole process under my question.