# How to bypass giving username and password each time when push something in remote repo?

Tags: git

When I run `git push remote origin` I have to give username and password. It is very important to make updated the remote repository when working in a team. For this reason I have to push when I modify/add something.

But, each time giving username and password is annoying.

Comment: Try SSH instead.

Comment: @Jules give command and procedure, plz.

Comment: (https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595863/7976758

Answer (score 2):

```
git config credential.helper store
```

then

```
 git pull
```

provide username and password and those details will be stored on disk.

Comment: @RonanBoiteau said that this is dangerous. Will you agree?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to **store your credentials in cache**:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

With this setting, next time you input your credentials, Git will remember them.

***Warning:*** Git will store your passwords *unencrypted*, this might be dangerous! You could go for a SSH authentication instead, it would be more secure.