# Git: Clone in VS Code returns "Permission denied, please try again" - git clone in terminal works

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

`Git: Clone` in Visual Studio Code on a mac returns `Permission denied, please try again`. From terminal within Visual Studio Code it works to perform `git clone`.

In Visual Studio Code on a Mac, I do the following:

1. I do `Git: Clone`
2. I input the ssh repository URL that is in the following format: `ssh://<username>@<repository-host>/<path>/<rep>.git`
3. I "Select Repository Location" folder, and get the following dialog:

[image: Dialog when Git fails]

**This function never asks me for any password!**

If I open the Git Log the output is this:

```
> git clone <ssh-repository-URL> <path>
Cloning into '<path>'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from <IP> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures for <username>
Disconnected from <IP> port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In terminal it works:

```
mac:rep username$ git clone 
Cloning into '<repository>'… <ssh-repository-URL>
The authenticity of host ‘<repository-host> (<repository-ip>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<fingerprint>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '<repository-host>,<repository-ip>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
remote: ...
remote: ...
remote: …
Receiving objects: 100% (.../...), ... | ... MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (.../...), done.
```

Any clues on why `Git: Clone` Visual Studio Code never asks for the server password?

Comment: From what you have mentioned above, I think that the VS Code rejects the remote because of the authenticity issue mentioned in the terminal part. Can you try cloning the repo using `https` instead of `ssh`?

Comment: @dstrants Thank you. I will update the question, as Git: Clone does never ask for the password to the repository server. In Terminal I can type the password. About https, I do not think this is supported by our local repository server.

Comment: Did you add a password to your ssh key?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Many thanks! This question actually led me to a way of solving the problem, as I was not aware that you could only use ssh URLs in the Git: Clone when a ssh key is set up correctly.

Comment: May you add your solution as an answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Added

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlaying functionality in `Git: Clone` does not seem to have any interaction with the user after setting the repository URL and choosing the destination folder.

To get a ssh-repository to work with Visual Studio Code you need to do the following:

1. Open terminal
2. Run `ssh-keygen` to generate ssh key pair
3. Run `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa <username>@<repository-host>`

Derived from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595848/3008081) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595858/3008081).

VS Code User Guide on Version Control has the following question/answer under Common Questions:

[Can I use SSH Git authentication with VS Code?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_can-i-use-ssh-git-authentication-with-vs-code)
Yes, though VS Code works most easily with SSH keys without a passphrase. If you have a SSH key with a passphrase, you'll need to launch VS Code from a Git Bash prompt to inherit its SSH environment.

Comment: I suffered 3hrs to figure that passphrase use is not direct in vs code git cloning.