# How do I change my git account credentials without Windows Credentials Manager

Tags: git, windows-10, gitlab, credentials, git-push

I have my git client on Windows 10 machine. I attempted the push my code with invalid credentials once. Now whenever when I try to push the commit, it gives me HTTP Basic:

```
Access Denied fatal: Authentication failed exception.
```

This is due to my previous invalid credentials, I assume. I tried to change my saved credentials using Windows Credentials Manager but WCM is blocked in my company because of security policy.

Can you please help me, how I can change my already stored credentials without Windows Credentials Manager?

```
$ git push origin master
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://my-host/gitlab/teamx/myapp.git/'
```

Comment: Would be acceptable to use ssh keys instead? You won't relay in WCM anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To save credentials, you can `clone` a repository by setting a *username* and *password* on the command line:

```
$ git clone https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

The *username* and *password* will be stored in the `.git/config` file as a part of the *remote repository* URL.

If you have *already cloned* a repository without setting *username* and *password* on the command line, you can always *update* the remote URL by running the following command:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

To save username and password to an existing repository, run the following command to enable credentials storage in your Git repository:

```
$ git config [--global] credential.helper store
```

(`--global` to enable credentials globally)

When credentials storage is enabled, the first time you `pull` or `push` from the remote Git repository, you will be asked for a *username* and *password*, and then it will be saved in `~/.git-credentials`.

During the next communications with the remote Git repository, you won’t have to provide the *username* and *password*.

Each credential in `~/.git-credentials` file is stored on its *own line* as a URL like:

```
https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@github.com
```

Look also at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git). You can that also do with *SSH-authentication* (look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once) question).